# Calling WP functions outside of functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to call WordPress functions outside of the `functions.php` file of a WordPress theme in a non-standard WP-theme file?

I'm developing some sort of supplementary framework on top of WordPress that pre-organises data from the WP database so I can call them with jQuery and create a single-page experience.

I've tried to call the WP function from a `post.php` file (in the theme root), which is not a default file for a WP-theme. Communication to/from `post.php` and front-end jQuery works fine, it's just the file that can't access the WP functionality. For example:

PHP themefolder/post.php:

```
//function to get ALL posts, don't use to save server capacity
function fetch_all(){
    $posts = get_posts(); //<-- this is a WP function, it doesn't work

    /* however this line below makes the function return some data
        $posts = 'testing if function works';
    */

    if( isset( $posts )){
        echo json_encode( $posts );
        exit();
    }

    echo json_encode( 'no data to return...' );
}
```

When including post.php in functions.php I get the same result: nothing. I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503014/wordpress-using-functions-outside-of-wordpress) method, but that seems to elaborate as I'm working within a WP environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Include `wp-blog-header.php` and set `WP_USE_THEMES` to `false` at the start of your file.

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );  
require('wp-blog-header.php'); # adjust your path

# write the rest of your codes here.
```

Comment: Wow thanks! Works straight of! Does this allow the usage of all the WP functions straight away or does more need to be included to use all functions defined in the WP codex?

Comment: You've got all functions available. Note that functions still need to be hooked when necessary.

Comment: I used the same code for my work but one problem still persists that is, the wordpress theme loads into the page. How do I resolve this? (WP version:3.8)