# Loading php pages outside of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I want to load a page, /foo.php, on my server that has wordpress installed, without adding this page into Wordpress.

Right now any http request to /foo.php returns a 404.

How can I load content outside of wordpress without creating pages in the template?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling WP functions outside of functions.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058074/calling-wp-functions-outside-of-functions-php)

Comment: No, I don't want to do anything related to Wordpress. I want WP to sit nicely in its corner (/blog) and just run there. I want to load my own content on the rest of the page .. having nothing to do with WP.

Comment: I tried adding: 'define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );  
require('wp-blog-header.php');' to the page like that other question, but that does not work. The page still 404s.

Comment: It should work without referencing to wordpress. Make sure your file is in the correct location and that it's readable by the web server.

Comment: The file is in the root and it 404s. If I make a subdirectory, move the folder there and rename it to index.php it loads, but any php file in there 404s as well.

Comment: does it work with permalinks off?

Comment: You guys are impossible. Why the down vote? The OP asks a valid question. You just didn't understood what he was asking.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It was in the .htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/([^-]*)$ /$1.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The top rules from Wordpress were mucking everything up. By removing or commenting them out, normal pages will load regardless of whether the user calls /foo or /foo.php

This is the working .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /blog/
# RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
# RewriteRule ^/([^-]*)$ /$1.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```